# STM32 memory page size

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, memory

I can't find the size of a page of memory in an STM32L0 (specifically STM32L053R8, see DocID 025844).  I don't see a referenced as to the size of a page of memory.

Note:  This is also in reference to the native boot-loader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find this information in the reference manual at [page 50](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00095744.pdf#page=50) (chapter 3 - Flash program memory and data EEPROM).

There is the actual organization of the non volatile memory.

For this device a page of flash is 128 Bytes.